# Change select pin of USB Host library

Tags: usb

#### TL;DR

With regards to the [USB host library](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0):

- Which is the correct file to modify the Arduino pin used for the USB Host slave select (SS) line?

---

I would like to add USB host functionality, to a particular Arduino setup, whilst, also, being able to use an Ethernet/SD (or just SD) shield.

As both the Ethernet shield and USB Host shield use pin 10 to select the W5500 and MAX3421E respectively<sup>1</sup>, obviously I can not use a standard USB Host shield. However, I could employ one of the small form factor boards, such as the [USB Host Shield 2.0 Arduino UNO MEGA ADK Compatible Google Android ADK](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/182052269837) which I found on eBay:

[image: USB Host shield]

As this board is not in the usual shield "shape", one would not be constrained by which pin to connected to which MAX3421E input/output, in particular the chip select (SS) input. So, one could use a pin (or pins) that is not reserved by the Ethernet shield.

*However*, it does not appear to be possible to simply specify the "select pin" (i.e. the Arduino pin connected to the SS line) when using the [USB Host shield library](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0) (or any of the pins used by the library), in `setup()`.

Therefore, I wondered if it was possible to modify the library, so that the pin used to select the USB/MAX3421E could be changed, either by:

- "Hardcoding" a *different* "select" pin number into a header file;
- Adding an argument to the `Init()` method, or;
- Adding a method to the `USB` class, such as `Usb.DefineSelect()`.

The latter two options, I could work through, given the time. However, as a quick and dirty hack, where would I hardcode in a change from pin 10 to a pin of my choosing? Does anyone know? Has anyone had to do this?

---

#### Nitty-gritty

I have had a look through the library to see where pin 10 is defined as the chip select, and [avrpins.h](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/avrpins.h) looked like a possible candidate for modification, although it would be rather "rude" (for want of a better word) and probably mess up the other boards.

[usbhost.h](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/usbhost.h) seems a much better proposition. Looking at usbhost.h, the [lines 88-91](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/usbhost.h#L88):

```
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || (__AVR_ATmega2560__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega32U4__) || defined(__AVR_AT90USB646__) || defined(__AVR_AT90USB1286__)
typedef SPi< Pb1, Pb2, Pb3, Pb0 > spi;
#elif  defined(__AVR_ATmega168__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega328P__)
typedef SPi< Pb5, Pb3, Pb4, Pb2 > spi;
```

Looking at the statement

```
typedef SPi< Pb5, Pb3, Pb4, Pb2 > spi;
```

the last argument appears to be the pin used for *select*. For the Uno (ATmega328P), in avrpins.h ([line 535](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/avrpins.h#L535)) `Pb2` is `P10` (pin 10), so I could substitute `Pb2` for some other pin definition, i.e. `Pd5` for `P5` (pin 5) ([line 529](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/avrpins.h#L529) in avrpins.h).

However, what I don't understand is that for the statement

```
typedef SPi< Pb1, Pb2, Pb3, Pb0 > spi;
```

which deals with the Mega (ATmega2560), in avrpins.h ([line 512](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/avrpins.h#L512)) `Pb0`is `P53` (pin 53). As `Pb4` is actually `P10` (pin 10) ([line 466](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/avrpins.h#L466)), why is `Pb0` en lieu of `Pb4` used? That doesn't tie up with the fact that Pin 10 is used for both the Uno and Mega boards. It seems to suggest the pin 10 is used on the Uno and pin 53 is used on the Mega. Unless I have misinterpreted the `typedef`.

---

#### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> For the USB host shield, from [Arduino USB Host Shield](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoUSBHostShield)

> Arduino communicates with the MAX3421E using the SPI bus (through the
> ICSP header). This is on digital pins 10, 11, 12, and 13 on the Uno
> and pins 10, 50, 51, and 52 on the Mega. On both boards, pin 10 is
> used to select the MAX3421E. Pins 7, 8 and 9 are used for GPX, INT and
> RES pins.

The key piece of information here is that pin 10 is used by *both* the Uno and Mega boards.

For the Ethernet shield, from [Arduino Ethernet Shield V2](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield)

> Arduino communicates with both the W5500 and SD card using the SPI bus
> (through the ICSP header). This is on digital pins 10, 11, 12, and 13
> on the Uno and pins 50, 51, and 52 on the Mega. On both boards, pin 10
> is used to select the W5500 and pin 4 for the SD card. These pins
> cannot be used for general I/O. On the Mega, the hardware SS pin, 53,
> is not used to select either the W5500 or the SD card, but it must be
> kept as an output or the SPI interface won't work.
>
> Note that because the W5500 and SD card share the SPI bus, only one at
> a time can be active. If you are using both peripherals in your
> program, this should be taken care of by the corresponding libraries.
> If you're not using one of the peripherals in your program, however,
> you'll need to explicitly deselect it. To do this with the SD card,
> set pin 4 as an output and write a high to it. For the W5500, set
> digital pin 10 as a high output.

Here, yet again, the key piece of information here is that pin 10 is used by *both* the Uno and Mega boards to select the Ethernet.

Comment: It look like you are correct, and that you should edit the usbhost.h file.  Not sure what you mean in the second question. The library uses the Arduinos SS pin. It does have to use this pin, but this prevents the pin from being an input and accidentally putting the atmega into SPI slave mode. The library also prefers to have all the pins on Port B.

Comment: @Gerben - Thanks for the confirmation of the first question. I have edited my post to try to clarify what my second question is, which is "shouldn't the last argument to the `typedef` for the Mega board be `Pb4` and not `Pb0`?" Maybe I need to recheck my understanding of the code, in the morning.

Comment: Trying to put both an Ethernet adapter and USB host adapter on an ATmega based Arduino is evidence of bad hardware selection.  You should probably either consider something that does both natively (for example some of the STM32F4's, and likely choices from other vendors) or unless your needs are very narrow and never expected to change, more likely a more sophisticated system capable of running an actual operating system.

Comment: Like I said, pin PB0 is the SS of the ATMega. When using SPI you shouldn't use this pin as an INPUT. It's therefor a good idea of the library maker to choose that pin, so it's always an OUTPUT. Also pin 53 is close to the other SPI pins. Using pin 5 would be at the other side of the board, which make wiring messy pretty quick. No big reason to choose PB0, just a few small reasons.

Comment: @Gerben - Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. At first I couldn't understand what you meant, but after re-reading [SPI library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/SPI), I see that the source of my confusion is that P53 (Mega) and P10 (Uno) are the Arduino's SS pin, which obviously must be set as an output, to maintain them as the SPI master. I was looking for the point in the code where pin 10 is set to select the USB shield's SS line, _not_ the Arduino's SS line, if that makes sense... So the `typedef`s that I found in `usbhost.h` are _not_ what I should be looking at.

Comment: @Gerben - After trawling most of the source files, I have found the point where `P10` is set as the USB SS line. It is, in fact, at [line 43 in `UsbCore.h`](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/UsbCore.h#L43). It seems at bit ruthless to modify this file, but that is where the change needs to be made. See my posted answer.

Comment: I don't get it. The Arduino has a SS pin, but you can ignore this if you aren't using the the Arduino as an SPI slave. If you don't use the Arduino as a slave, the SS pin is just a regular input/output pin.

Comment: @Gerben - I think that we have our wires crossed, so to speak... :-) My answer below will hopefully clarify what I mean. If not, then I will need to reword my answer. The Arduino is the SPI Master, and the small USB host device, that I show in my question, will be the SPI slave. With my suggested modification to the code, Pin 5 would go to the USB Host SS line and then there would be no conflict with the Ethernet board that uses Pin 10 for its SS line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to change the Arduino pin used to select the USB Host board, in order words, where the device's SS line is assigned to an Arduino pin (with the Arduino as the SPI Master and the USB host is the SPI slave), the line to change is at [line 43 in `UsbCore.h`](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/UsbCore.h#L43):

```
typedef MAX3421e<P10, P9> MAX3421E; // Official Arduinos (UNO, Duemilanove, Mega, 2560, Leonardo, Due etc.), Intel Edison, Intel Galileo 2 or Teensy 2.0 and 3.x
```

So to use pin 5, for example, en lieu of pin 10, the line would become:

```
typedef MAX3421e<P5, P9> MAX3421E; // Official Arduinos (UNO, Duemilanove, Mega, 2560, Leonardo, Due etc.), Intel Edison, Intel Galileo 2 or Teensy 2.0 and 3.x
```

The clue was in the comment on [line 27 in `UsbCore.h`](https://github.com/felis/USB_Host_Shield_2.0/blob/master/UsbCore.h#L27)

```
/* shield pins. First parameter - SS pin, second parameter - INT pin */
```

With this suggested modification to the code, Pin 5 would go to the USB Host SS line and then there would be no conflict with the Ethernet board that uses Pin 10 for its SS line.

---

This issue, I have subsequently discovered, is covered by the [USB Host Shield Hardware Manual](https://www.circuitsathome.com/usb-host-shield-hardware-manual/), under the **Interface modifications** section. I guess I should have just read the manual first! RTFM...

---

#### Clarification of the issue

I must be honest that my question was somewhat confused. After having read the [SPI library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/SPI), it states that

> **Note about Slave Select (SS) pin on AVR based boards**
>
> All AVR based boards have an SS pin that is useful when they act as a
>   slave controlled by an external master. Since this library supports
>   only master mode, this pin should be set always as OUTPUT otherwise
>   the SPI interface could be put automatically into slave mode by
>   hardware, rendering the library inoperative.
>
> It is, however, possible to use any pin as the Slave Select (SS) for
>   the devices. For example, the Arduino Ethernet shield uses pin 4 to
>   control the SPI connection to the on-board SD card, and pin 10 to
>   control the connection to the Ethernet controller.

With respect to the first paragraph, the Uno uses pin 10 and Mega uses pin 53 as the Arduino SS line - so that must be set as an output in order for the Arduino to be the Master. Are realising this as being my source of confusion, it became apparent that the `typedef` statements, in `usbhost.h`, were *not* where I should have been looking to change the device's Slave Select pin.

With respect to the second paragraph,  I want to use pin 5 (for example) to control the Slave Select (SS) for the USB Host device, instead of the default pin 10.

Comment: The link seems to have died and [this google site search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Acircuitsathome.com+%22running+multiple+slave+devices+on+arduino+spi+bus%22) finds nothing seemingly related

Comment: See section _Interface modifications_ in the USB Host Shield [Hardware Manual](https://circuitsathome.com/usb-host-shield-hardware-manual/). Address updated.

Comment: So, it is the same link as was in my answer?

Comment: Yes, that is the only surviving link I can find. It is linked from the README of the library repo on GitHub.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thats a shame. I never got around to seeing the original link that you posted. I wonder if it was dramatically different.